# error from test method - "apex job is already scheduled for execution"

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, failing-tests, asyncapexjob

I have a batch apex which starts itself after x mins.
this is done in `finish()` method using , `system.scheduleBatch()` method.

below is how the batch looks like,

```
global class my_ProcessPurge_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global String query;

    global my_ProcessPurge_Batch() {
     //initialize query string here         
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {    
        //some DML statements here          
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
       //send email of the result
      //schedule next batch
      my_ProcessPurge_Batch nextBatch = new my_ProcessPurge_Batch();
      //job should start executing after 24 hrs
      //scope is 1000
      System.scheduleBatch(nextBatch, 'my_ProcessPurge_Batch', 1440, 1000);     
    }
}
```

I am trying to test this batch. My test method is as follows,

```
@isTest static void testProcessPurge() {
    Test.startTest();
    //populate test data
    //start batch
    my_ProcessPurge_Batch purgeBatch = new my_ProcessPurge_Batch();
    database.executeBatch(purgeBatch);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

I am receiving error -

> System.AsyncException: The Apex job named "my_ProcessPurge_Batch" is
>   already scheduled for execution.

Error is thrown in the finish() method when I call database.executeBatch() method

There is no other batch running in my org with this name. I also tried to change the name of the
batch but it didn't help.

I can run the same `database.executeBatch()` method successfully as anonymous code.
It only fails from test method.

any idea what is causing this error and how can I fix it ?

I can use `isRunningTest()` method and ignore the execution of `executeBatch()` method but I don't think that answers the question.

Also, if I manage to skip the method call using `isRunningTest()`, would this cause issue during production deployment when I already have job with the same name already scheduled ?

Comment: where did you check for current scheduled jobs? did you check under setup--> monitor --> scheduled jobs ?

Comment: yes, I did check under setup-->monitor-->scheduled jobs

Comment: is this v32 or an earlier version? Did you try with an earlier version?

Comment: this is for api version 28

Comment: I also updated the version to v31 but that didn't help

Comment: Ever figure out what happened? I'm seeing an error like this.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same

Answer (score 0):

please find the solution of your question
**error from test method - “apex job is already scheduled for execution”**

```
@isTest static void testProcessPurge() {
Test.startTest();
//populate test data
//start batch
for ( AsyncApexJob aJob : [ Select id ,Status from AsyncApexJob] )
{
System.AbortJob(aJob.Id);
}
    my_ProcessPurge_Batch purgeBatch = new my_ProcessPurge_Batch();
    database.executeBatch(purgeBatch);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```